# Is there any fundamental reason Julia doesn't support abstract multiple inheritance?

Tags: julia

For example, I want to be able to do something along these lines:

```
abstract Tree
abstract SupervisedModel
type DecisionTree <: Tree, SupervisedModel
```

This currently isn't possible in Julia. Is this due to any fundamental reasons, or is it simply not implemented yet?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This issue is currently under discussion. It appears that the implementation is complex and results in many edge cases, but that there are no fundamental reasons why this couldn't be a language feature: https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/5

Also, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/julia-dev/xBzQqhq5aLM/oUWpCqfaI30J